An Optimal way to approach Math Olympiad Number Theory problems
Q. Positive real numbers a,b satisfy the equation:
$\frac{a}{b}$ $\left(\frac{a}{b} + 2\right)$ + $\frac{b}{a}\left(\frac{b}{a} +   2\right) = 2022$
Find $n$ such that:
$\sqrt{n}$ = $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$ + $\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}$

While solving this,
I assumed $ \frac{a}{b}  = x$ and $ \frac{b}{a} $ = $ \frac{1}{x} $
This simplifies the equation to:
$ x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} + 2x + \frac{2}{x} = 2022 $
Now, upon further simplification:
$ (x + \frac{1}{x})^2 - 2 + 2(x + \frac{1}{x}) + 3 = (45)^2 $
[In my free time I pick up random numbers and just mess around. 2025 was $45^2$, I remember]
Then:
$ (x + \frac{1}{x} + 1)^2 = 45^2 $
$ \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a} + 1 = 45 $
$ \left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)^2 + 2 = 46 $
$ \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} + \sqrt{\frac{b}{a}} = \sqrt{46} $
$ n = 46 $
So, what I wanted to know was that in Olympiad problems how should I think regarding solving something. For instance, in this problem, while solving it, I just went with the flow (added 3 because of 45 without knowing how it would solve the problem).

I’m of the belief that you can’t be taught to think in such a way to solve contest problems. Contest problems vary across different mathematical fields — number theory, algebra, combinatorics, geometry on the high school level. Practice problem and exercise solving helps one analyse the best course to solve a newly encountered problem.

So you already solved this....what is your question again?

For questions like this personally I would make an eqn out of $n$, but this was a welcome process too. The equation would be $(n^2-4n+2)+2(n-2)=2022$

IMO You had a great approach. You recognized that there is essentially one variable $ x = \frac{ a}{b}$, and rewrote the question in terms of that. $\quad$ (Echoing Gwen,) A possible improvement, is to set that one variable as $ n = x + \frac{1}{x} + 2 $ (which they already gave!).  Then we have $(n-2)^2 -2 + 2 ( n-2) + 3 = 2025$, or that $(n+44)(n-46) = 0 $. It is essentially the calculation that you did, in a simpler form.
